# Custom primary key value not being displayed correctly

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database

Hi hope you are having a good day ! ,I have a Laravel application where I'm using a custom primary key for my Ticket model. In the store method of my TicketController, I generate a random string for the ticketID column using uniqid(). When I check the database that im using phpMyAdmin, I can see that the ticketID values are correctly generated and stored.

but, when I try to display or work with the ticketID in my views, only a small part of the generated ID is being shown specially the numbers . For example, if the generated ticketID is "6045e16d8db80" picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3NKC.png),
in my views or when trying to access it, I only see "6045".picture [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wmzbn.png)

Here's the relevant code in my TicketController:

```
`public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $ticket = new Ticket();
        $ticket->ticketID = uniqid();
        $ticket->sujet = $request->input('sujet');
        $ticket->description = $request->input('description');
        $ticket->status = 0; // Set default status
        $ticket->Priorite = $request->input('priorite');
        $ticket->user_id = Auth::id(); // Associate the ticket with the authenticated user
        $ticket->save();    
        return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with('success', 'Ticket created successfully');
    }`
```

And here's how I'm trying to display the ticketID in my view:

```
` @foreach($tickets as $ticket)
        <tr class="bg-white border-b hover:bg-gray-100 text-black">
            <td class="px-6 py-4">{{ $ticket->ticketID }}</td>
@endforeach`
```

I'm not sure why only part of the ticketID is being displayed. Any insights or suggestions on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

and i already checked everything model schema my database too and the other colums work fine the problem is just in ticketid,

Comment: provide your db fetch query for  foreach($tickets as $ticket)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the Primary key has been an `INTEGER` field by default the day since they wrote MySQL ;)

You should add `$keyType` and `$incrementing` const in your mode for this.

```
class Ticket extends Model
{
    public $incrementing = false;

    protected $keyType = 'string';

    protected $primaryKey = 'ticketID';

}
```

Finally, run

```
php artisan config:clear
```

---

> Take a look at ***naming conversation*** (DB column `ticketID` should be `ticket_id`, Not a must. But good to follow)

Comment: thank you so much , you saved my day  I truly appreciate the time you took to assist me with my code. Your help made a huge difference. Thanks again! have a good day !

Comment: Actually both , but you explained it so well that i surprised it worked from the first try i was struggling with this for like 4 days thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

Primary key always cast to an integer, so update your model with the required datatype for primary key

```
protected $keyType = 'string';
```

Otherwise, try `getOriginal()` method, just replace the below code

```
@foreach($tickets as $ticket)
        <tr class="bg-white border-b hover:bg-gray-100 text-black">
            <td class="px-6 py-4">{{ $ticket->getOriginal('ticketID') }}</td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks it worked i appreciate the time and effort you made to help me made this  have a good day !!